# Laravel not finding Elixir JS and CSS files - Not defined in manifest error

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

I am new to Elixir and need help resolve error below.  I am not clear how I can resolve?

> "File app.js not defined in asset manifest"

I have in my Blade files the below two lines which are being pointed to as causing the error.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('app.css') }}">
```

`<script src="{{ elixir('app.js') }}"></script>`

rev-manifest file is as below: It is in public/build/

```
{
  "app.css": "css/app-scheduler-7b1b6567b7f6fa730140.css",
  "app.js": "js/app-scheduler.js"
}`
```

Here is the gulp file `const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

```
elixir((mix) => {
mix.sass('app.scss')
   .webpack('app.js');
});
```

`

App.js is available in resources/assets/app.js 
I have found these webconfig files? Is there anything I should try here

```
 output: {
    filename: 'js/[name]-scheduler.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/build'),
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name]-scheduler.js',
    publicPath: '/build/'
```

Comment: what is the path of the **rev-manifest** file?

Comment: It is in public/build/

Comment: Try move it to 'public/'

Comment: No luck. in public/ it is still saying not defined in manifest

Comment: Where is the rev-manifest file called from? ?

Answer (score 0):

Your css is inside a path (/css).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: I have tried adding css but not luck. Where is the rev-manifest file called from?